# Typescript: variable possibly undefined inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

TLDR; Checking variable before using it in a anonymous function still TS warns variable possibly undefined

In the below code example variable `baseDirId` is checked if undefined then passed to array.map function but TS warns `baseDirId` can be undefined.

// [Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgE7yQgvAghjAnlMBACiwC4FUBLKAcwEoMA+BAb1AWQFM4BXJKbAgDUCAEQAjADacAFqNABfUKEixEWJDRjkWCcTk4ARSkgCSAE3JVaCAD4IeUc5wBm1TuYQKMrdnoPGZpZiMBAAtpyU5vIgHAD0cf4wRiYW5I7OblAeisrg0PAU4ZwAgkhomADaEtIyAIyiADRiUrIATKIAunmqhS6OYHU+OPiERHTkAApI4ZTJADwAbhBRzOjMbLEIcEi4vlvxiSUwMDwRSSlBCGBYAuKcDk6u7uZ+HNKI+smBFsOaMAA6L6XCx5DiHBAAFSQlBoNE4aEoLguP08c0emRebwQSOIAEJgaiGJtweDep8AiYAPLiABWPl0UXIokWWEkUQoO2oNFEXmxHEJqU8mEFSBptIBUWxSgO1wKEGkAMkEBoRDguAADpwIMjRRY6GDwQkUULrrdPg9brg4DJuQgIDaEdsZLdBNYaAhsbi1ZrtbrKVc8ehMKJ3aJifyuLx+AhprNkgCkJxaZwwHAiKIAEIGBCBLgwDUFB7UVns6IG2Uy7HGgDqMj26L1ngABu67BjntlzM2cbAog8UDszZJJHpOMqAO4ITiLTgCLAuOBOrDiCCz64yVMAaxg2PJelqGgqRQiZSQALCWA1RCIpYY62QqCITboFdJvQVnCVKpIE6wlEQOMwjmL82UkZ9D3KV8-G8G44DAGRiARJAI1lD9FWQiAkCIZC3z5EAqxAfoCDqcYATghCcPKJg5VgT8AUw7DcIrIA)

```js
const rstr = async (a: string) => {
  return a + "bleh"
}

const args: { baseDirId: string | undefined } = {
  baseDirId: "someid"
  // baseDirId: undefined
}

const someArr = ["bleh1", "bleh2"]

const func1 = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    // Assume baseDirId can be undefined
    let baseDirId = args.baseDirId

    // Trigger if baseDirId is undefined
    if (!baseDirId) {
      const baseDirObj = { id: "valid string" }
      baseDirId = baseDirObj.id
    }
    console.log(typeof baseDirId)

    // baseDirId cant be anything other than a string 
    if (typeof baseDirId !== "string") {
      return Promise.reject("Base Dir response invalid")
    }

    // Why is baseDirId `string | undefined` inside rstr call below even after above checks
    const bleharr = someArr.map((val) => rstr(baseDirId))
    console.log(await Promise.all(bleharr))
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

func1().catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Is there any possible case where `baseDirId` can be `undefined` ?

Why wont TS allow it ? Better way to do it ?

Comment: the issue is types are conflicting, even though you did put in checks to make sure baseDirId is a string, but that ensures that value of it is string, meaning the type defined is still either a string or undefined. You can use something like `baseDirId as string` to explicitly cast it to string, this is possible because you already made sure it will be string in above code and shouldnt break things, else change the type of `rstr` function's parameter to match `baseDirId`

Comment: I would prefer not to explicitly type cast `baseDirId as string`. Also in the code I make sure the var is not `undefined` (line 18) then check the only other possible type `string` (line 25). Thus I dont understand what you meant by 
 "but that ensures that value of it is string, meaning the type defined is still either a string or undefined."

Comment: I assume this is because of `setTimeout(() => console.log(baseDirId), 1000); setTimeout(() => baseDirId = undefined, 500);`. Or in other words: A callback might be called at a later point in time, and the value might be undefined then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's slightly change the code to

```
 return () => someArr.map((val) => rstr(baseDirId))
```

so instead of calling `.map` directly it might get run at a later point in time. Some other code might've written undefined into `baseDirId` in the meantime. Therefore to correctly infer the type, Typescript would've to check that no other code somewhen overrides the variable. That's quite a complicated task (it could even be impossible in some corner cases). Also this gets even more complicated if our inner function was called at multiple places:

```
let mutable: string | undefined = /*...*/;
const inner = () => fn(mutable); // << how to infer this?

mightCall(inner); // if called back here, mutable would be "string | undefined"
if(typeof mutable === "string") mightCall(inner); // if called here, mutable could be narrowed down to "string", but only if mightCall calls back synchronously

mutable = undefined; // if mightCall calls back asynchronously, 'mutable' would have to be inferred as undefined
```

Therefore when functions access variables from the outer scope, the Typescript compiler *assumes the widest possible type*. Type narrowing only works for the function's body itself. To narrow down the type you'd either need a type assertion, or alternatively copy the value into a `const`:

```
 let mutable: string | undefined = /*...*/;
 if(typeof mutable !== "string") return;
 // mutable get's narrowed down to string here due to the typeof type guard
 const immutable = mutable;
  //        ^ inferred as string, this is the widest possible type
```

This also [works in your case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-covygq8KyAA).

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript does not check types and even change types at runtime, so `baseDirId` type would always is `string | undefined` unless you do narrow types or something else for type, so there are many options you can try.

**1. Use default**

```
let baseDirId = args.baseDirId || "valid string"
```

**2. Do a conditional value check**

```
if(args.baseDirId){
  let baseDirId = args.baseDirId
  // ...
  // do something you want
}
```

But you can't do this directly in following snippet, since you used `let` to declare `baseDirId`,  and then it won't work due to that it can be changed to `undefined` at any time unless it's declared via `const`

```
if(baseDirId){
  const bleharr = someArr.map((val) => rstr(baseDirId))
}
```

****3. Use `!`** [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)**

When you're sure it must be exsiting and you don't want to change anything else

```
const bleharr = someArr.map((val) => rstr(baseDirId!))
```

Comment: Will it possible to narrow down baseDirId type to `string` ?

Comment: @Solaris Sure, you can do that, but since you used `let` to declare the `baseDirId`, even if you use do a conditional value check, seems like it won't work due to that it can be changed to `undefined` at any time