# Typescript not seeing gaurd through a async IIFE

Tags: typescript

I have a definition of type `Payment` like this:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiAthAdsKBeKBvAUFKAZwEsATALiOACdiUBzKAHyhQFcAbDgblwF9cAMzYoAxsGIB7FFFKTiwABRgEyNIUrwkqYAG0AugEoc+KCu3qAdIMnUAonFEALZap2YAfCYIFigqIqmPmZuaJYkpEFQxnjBwaLShOgRlEm0DJghFsDhZLxxPlHBinCEIGIBxhhesQU+CShJRGSpNHSMWOZqORH5dQRFPnyGioZRAgTDvHxAA)

```
type Payment = {
  sid: string | null;
}

function doit(payments: Payment[]) {
  payments.forEach(payment => {
    if (
      payment.sid
    ) {
        // this is good
        const sid: string = payment.sid;

        (async () => {

          // this fails
          const sid: string = payment.sid;
          
        })()
    }
  });
}
```

The problem above is that `const sid` is seen as being possibly null. Now I know I can move the gaurd into that IIFE, however I know for a fact it's going to be truthy.

Comment: I found this "*when functions access variables from the outer scope, the Typescript compiler assumes the widest possible type*" from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67148354/1858357), but what's interesting is that it works fine if you remove the `async`.

Comment: Thanks @BizzyBob for that comment and link! Its very interesting it works without the `async`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a missing feature of TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#30625](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30625).

---

In general the TypeScript compiler does not have the resources to do proper [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) on closed-over values across function boundaries.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for a full discussion of this.  For most situations, the type checker does not track *when* a function will be called, so it doesn't know if any narrowings that occur outside the function body will be in effect inside the function body.  Any such narrowings are effectively reset inside the function.  Even if a human being could look at the code and see that the values should be narrowed, the compiler does not do this.

Now, for [immediately invoked function expressions (IIFEs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), in particular, the compiler *does* "inline" the function body in terms of control flow analysis.  This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#8849](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8849).  If you remove the `async` keyword, the compiler recognizes that the function body is in the same narrowing state as the outer scope, and so `payment.sid` is still non-null.

Unfortunately this was not done for immediately invoked [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).  In general such functions tend to have [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in them, and once you pass an `await` then the compiler cannot be sure when it will be run and whether previously narrowed values are still narrowed.

In the particular case of the part of an immediately invoked `async` function before the first `await`, it would be *possible* for the compiler to keep the narrowing.  It just isn't implemented.  As I mentioned at the start, microsoft/TypeScript#30625 is an open issue asking for this.  But there doesn't seem to be much community support for or awareness of it.  You *could* go there and give it a  but I wouldn't hold out much hope that anything will change.

For now the best thing you can do is copy the guarded value to a new `const` and then use that within the inner function scope, like:

```
if (payment.sid) {
  const sid: string = payment.sid;
  (async () => {
    sid // <-- just use this here  
  })()
}
```

This works because a `const` cannot be reassigned, and so whatever type it is known to have at its initialization will be its type in all scopes in which it exists.  Yes, it would be nice if you didn't have to do this, but the general problem is unsolvable as per microsoft/TypeScript#9998, so there will always be situations where you need to do "extra" or redundant work to help the compiler follow what you already know.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiAthAdsKBeKBvAUFKAZwEsATALiOACdiUBzKAHyhQFcAbDgblwF9cAMzYoAxsGIB7FFFKTiwABRgEyNIUrwkqYAG0AugEoc+KCu3qAdIMnUAonFEALZap2YAfCYIFigqK4WwJYkpMZ4Pj6i0oTooZSxtAyYZm5oIWS8kQSKcIQgYgHGGF4R2QShUAD0VVAAPAC0DVAAVmyxUO3QwE7EhFBOENTQUKaRfIaKhmNQAgQTvHxAA)

Comment: Thanks jcalz for such an in-depth explanation! I also tried making it "Readonly", but that didnt work. Your explanation above is awesome thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`string | null` is the correct type, because it could quite easily be null. For example:

```
const payments: Payment[] = [{ sid: "XYZ" }]

doit(payments)
payments[0].sid = null
```

The `if` clause evaluates to `true`, because it's hit synchronously, but by the time the 200ms timeout expires, `sid` is already `null`.

Comment: Oops I removed the `delay` sorry.

Comment: @Noitidart the guard needs to be inside the function.

Comment: Thanks @Evert but why, I wouldn't have got to that point, and typescript clearly sees on the line immediately above it, that another gaurd isn't needed.

Comment: In your (current) particular example, you are right. Typescript is not perfect. Never has been, likely never will be. It follows basic rules such as 'In a closure, previous type guards may no longer be valid'. With each version Typescript has gotten better with analyzing code.

Comment: Is it possible to make Typescript see that it is read only?